# Snake Pygame - Nothing happening

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to create a snake game but the code I wrote is not working.

Here is the code (Stackover doesn't really let me paste it correctly so I am linking a pastbin, sorry for that):
http://pastebin.com/FZRS3PGg

I can blit the snake but it is not moving and I am not even sure if I have written the "general comands RIGHT LEFT DOWN UP" correctly.

Could you please help me figuring out what is wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask us a precise question, we won't work through your code. Downvoting.

Comment: How can I make the snake move, because it stays freeze but I thought I did the moving part correctly. The snake is blitted but it doesn't move.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem. Your `pygame.event.get()` loop only checks if the event is quit, and then loops back. You need to move those three lines back one indentation level, so that the loop includes all the if statements.

Next time, please cut down your code to the minimum, and post it here rather than on a pastebin: there are actually very good instructions on how to format the code correctly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast reply, I have tried what you adviced me to do but nothing changed, I tried to move the remaining part 1 identation back as well but nothing changed,
The snake doesn't move and because of this I can not even check if it obeys to my keyboard comands.